# Mashup Qlik Sense - MIME invalido

Tags: angular, mime-type

Estou utilizando o Meshup com Angular 1.0.0 no Qlik Sense, quando importo a aplicação no navegador tenho o seguinte erro:

```
"O script de {caminho do meu script}, foi carregado apesar do seu tipo MIME("text/html") não ser um tipo MIME Javascript válido"
```

Todos os script dentro do html estão sendo especificados com o type="text/javascript", não achei nada relacionado com essa falha na documentação.

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).